# Numpy and Pandas not working in my python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, module

**Pandas and Numpy import problem**

whenever I try to import pandas or numpy nothing shows in the terminal.

for e.g

```
import numpy as np
inputs = [1, 2, 3, 2.5]

weights = [[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0],
           [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
           [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]]

biases = [2, 3, 0.5]

output = np.dot(weights, inputs)
print(output)
```

the above code should have printed the output but nothing is printed in the terminal
[image]

I have tried reinstalling python, pandas and numpy but nothing seems to work. I have checked for any conflicting packages.
also numpy and pandas works perfectly fine with anaconda but not working in my python idle or vscode.
its making the python idle restart.

**specifications**

1. python - 3.10.9
2. numpy - 1.24.3
3. pandas - 2.0.2

`output` menu:
[output menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIzT7.png)

Comment: Click on `OUTPUT` menu bar

Comment: If you were actually running that code, abd it had problem importing numoy, you'd get an error message.  No output means the script isn't running, or the 'runner' is not showing the output, whether its desired or error messages.

Comment: @GodIsOne the output menu is just showing:
_Loading configuration....
Done loading configuration_

Comment: @Azure paste the screen shot of `OUTPUT`

Comment: @GodIsOne i had pasted the scrnshot in the question tho don't know why it created a link

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, go to the `neural network` folder. Then, execute the following command:

```
python nnet.py
```

Otherwise, try with:

```
python3 nnet.py
```

Comment: this also didn't worked, nothing showed up in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something wrong with your settings in VS Code

Comment: oh can you specify the problem maybe?

Comment: I have the same version of python and 
numpy - 1.23.5
pandas - 1.5.3
And your code works for me in Jupyter and VS Code giving the answer:
[ 2.8   -1.79   1.885]
I have no clue what exactly is wrong in your case. The tiny possibility - different versions of the packages in python and anaconda virtenv.

Comment: Also pay attention to the 2nd row in the terminal with the red cross. Click on it. It may show you the code line with the error

Comment: i will try changing the package versions and as for the red cross i have tried clicking it but nothing related to the error also now when i run the code not even the red cross appears 

Comment: also as for the line of error i think it occur as soon as i import numpy or pandas 'cause when i just import numpy or pandas in python's built in idle the shell restarts

Comment: it is now working..... i changed my python package versions to yours and now it is working.... thank you so much